# selenium find element with tag started with "#"

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I want to scrape web and the structure looks like:

```
<iframe>
    #document
        <html>
            ......
        </html>
</iframe>
```

I need to step into "html" and click the button but I can't find a way to go  inside.

Is there any method to click button inside the "#tag_name"?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access elements inside an iframe you have to switch to that iframe.
In case this is the only iframe on the page it can be done with:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe'))
```

In case there are several iframes there you should locate them similarly to the other web elements

Comment: I see, but to access any element inside the iframe you first have to switch to the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to how we scrape the DOM for other tags.

```
<html>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

We usually write it like `"//div[@tag-name="<<value>>"]"`. Very similarly, we perform for frame as well.

Instead of writing it direct to access the elements, we switch to the frame and then access as below

```
driver.switch_to_frame("<<frame id or frame name>>")
driver.find_element(By.xpath, '//div[@tag-name="<<value>>"]').click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

OR

```
driver.switch_to_frame("<<frame id or frame name>>")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@tag-name="<<value>>"]")
element.click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: my problem can be written  as "//#document/div[@tag-name="<<value>>"]" if xpath allowed this format....

Comment: No it doesn't allow that  format. However, to access  anything inside a frame is to always switch to it and  then perform the rest of the things as required. Doesn't matter even if it is "#document" try to switch to the frame and then click. Let us know if this works

Comment: it doesn't work. The content is inside "#document" which can't be accessed